# Move items around within object in JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, json.net

Have some JSON

```
{
   "Items": [
   {
      "Name": "Hello",
      "Id": 1
   }
   {
      "Name": "World",
      "Id": 2
   }
}
```

And for various reasons (mainly cos people need to edit the file (don't ask)) would really like to move "Id" to before "Name".

```
{
   "Items": [
   {
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "Hello"
   }
   {
      "Id": 2,
      "Name": "World"
   }
}
```

We're using Json.NET - any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_Order.htm), use the `JsonPropertyAttribute` and the Order property.

```
public class SomeClass
{

  [JsonProperty(Order=2)]
  public string Name {get; set;}

  [JsonProperty(Order=1)]
  public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

Should appear as:

```
{
  "Id":0,
  "Name":null
}
```